# Java Selenium - how can I run many scenarios at the same time on RemoteWebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver, parallel-execution

I would like to run all 3 scenarios at once - I mean I want my computer to open 3 chrome browsers at the same time. Now the code opens 1 browser for one scenario, executes scenario, closes browser and then opens another browser for second scenario and so on.

How should I configure POM.xml file to achieve this ?
Is this called parallel execution or do I misunderstand this expression ?

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/java/features",
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/jsonReports/cucumber-report.json",
                "html:target/jsonReports/cucumber-report.html"},
        glue= {"stepDefs"} 
        )
public class TestRunner {
}
```

Feature file looks like this:

```
Feature: test of a webpage

  @desktop
  Scenario: Test landing page one
    Given Customer clicks something one 
    When Customer clicks something two
    Then Customer clicks something three
 
  @desktop
  Scenario: Test landing page two
    Given Customer clicks something one 
    When Customer clicks something two
    Then Customer clicks something three

  @desktop
  Scenario: Test landing page three
    Given Customer clicks something one 
    When Customer clicks something two
    Then Customer clicks something three
```

I have defined remote webdriver on my localhost

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.9.1.jar hub
java -jar selenium-server-4.9.1.jar node --hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register:5555

webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL), chromeOptions);
```

Thank you